# What is the step by step easiest way to create a product page for an online video course?

Tags: html, product

What I would like to create is just a product page for one online course I am about to release in a month or two.

The emphasis is really on simplicity here:

- The page should contain the necessary information about the product,
- An opportunity for the customer to be able to watch the first 3 lessons for free and then decide to pay for the rest if he likes it,
- A method to pay for the course and unluck the whole video course for that customer only.

I know HTML, CSS, and a little JavaScrpit already.

What should I learn to be able to create a page like this? Are there any good templates out there that I can use maybe?

Thank you!